# Why this TryParseExact form string to DateTime fails?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i have a method that parse a column, belongs to a DataTable ,from string to DateTime, this method accepts as parameters different formats of dates. Another classes are inherithing this method so i would like not to change it, because thay are working fine. My question is why in the case of s="31/1/2021" and format="dd/MM/yyyy" the conversion fails?

[image]

PD: I leave the method code here

```
    protected async Task<DataTable> ReplaceDateColumn(DataTable dataTable, int indexColumn, string nameNewColumn, string formatDate)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => ReplaceDateColumnOperation(dataTable, indexColumn, nameNewColumn, formatDate));
    }

    private DataTable ReplaceDateColumnOperation(DataTable dataTable, int indexColumn, string nameNewColumn, string formatDate)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(nameNewColumn, typeof(DateTime));
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            string format = formatDate;
            DateTime date;
            string s = row[indexColumn].ToString();
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                row[dataTable.Columns.Count - 1] = date;
            }
        }
        dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(indexColumn); //reomve string date
        dataTable.Columns[nameNewColumn].SetOrdinal(indexColumn); //set new column DateTime to first column
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: `MM` means _two_ places of month. meaning: `01` instead of `1`

Comment: complementing what @FranzGleichmann said, if you use only 1 place for month, you're looking for `M`. [Full list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: What's the point of this code? `row[indexColumn].ToString()` seems to be formatting an existing date as a string, then `DateTime.TryParseExact` tries to parse the string back into the original date using a *different* format, specifically the US format. That's guaranteed to fail everywhere except the US

Comment: I use to sort the dates after

Comment: Either `row[indexColumn]` is a `string`, in which case `ToString()` is a no-op or the entire method is a no-op

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: why it's a nop-op? You get an object and convert it to a string, so if that already a string this will be the same as casting it to string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter if the field contains a string, `ToString()` just returns the string itself.

Comment: If the column contains the date as `DateTime` then just cast it: `DateTime d = (DateTime)row[indexColumn];`. Then this paring problem vanishes!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, but `row[indexColumn]` returns `System.Object` and the `ToString` will give you the object as string. That's what OP wants to convert it to a `DateTime` in the next line. I guess this comes from excel or CSV and he wants to fix the type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter in that case a cast would be better. At the very least it would prevent accidental conversions to string. I suspect `ToString()` was used because a lot of quick&dirty forum posts use this instead of casting

Comment: `row[indexColumn]` returns a value **statically** typed as `object`. But the the object still might be a boxed `DateTime` object. Then just unbox it with `(DateTime)row[indexColumn]`. If it is a `string`, then do the same with `string`: `(string)row[indexColumn]`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: OP's screenshot and also his question clearly shows that it's just a plain string `"31/1/2021"`. if it was a `DateTime` the `ToString` would return `"31.01.2021 00:00:00"`(depending on his current culture, but always with time portion)

Comment: OK guys this data comes from excel files, i needed to parse the string dates to DateTime in order to sort them after. I dont know if better to cast the row as (string) or just use .ToString(), One is a metehod a other is a cast, maybe you can save no calling a method using a casting

Comment: I use the debugger row is the type of object not DateTime

Comment: Edgar Gomez you can find the underlying type of the `object` by querying the `DataColumn.DataType` property: `var type = dataTable.Columns[indexColumn].DataType;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dear your string is 31/1/2021, you should pad the character '1' from the left with '0' and size 2, like ->
31/01/2021 because your month format is "MM".
If your data is clean, you can change the format to M.
But if you have randomly generated dates with M and MM format you can clean your data inside memory with this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) {
        s = string.Join('/',
            s.Trim().Split('/')
            .Select(token => token.PadLeft(2, '0'))
            .ToArray()
            );
}
```